# How do you programmatically change default download directory on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, command-line, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to programmatically set default download location for my testcafe tests. Is there is an option to pass a command-line argument to change default download location while executing tests in chrome in headless mode?

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe doesn't have a CLI or a programmatic option for changing the browser's download behavior and [Сhrome doesn't have such a flag](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). To achieve this, you need to use the [setDownloadBehavior](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDownloadBehavior) DevTools Protocol's function in the following way:
`await t.testRun.browserConnection.provider.plugin.openedBrowsers[t.testRun.browserConnection.id].client.Page.setDownloadBehavior({ behavior: 'allow, downloadPath: '...' });`

Comment: Hey @Arseniy Rubtsov, this solution does not seem to work with newer versions of TestCafè (1.14.2) and Chrome (90.0.4430.72). Is there a new, alternative way to achieve the  same desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

To test file download you can use the [RequestLogger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestlogger/) feature instead of setting the default download directory. See the [check-downloaded-file-name-and-content](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/check-downloaded-file-name-and-content) example for more information.